# Access callback infinite loop in specific case

Tags: 7, nodes, redirection

I need to **limit node creation** to one item for a specific content_type (photography contest), and to **redirect the user to its photography** if he already posted one. The snippet below is almost working as expected.

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/add/slide']['access callback'] = '_mymodule_limit_slide';
}

function _mymodule_limit_slide () {
  global $user;
  if(user_access("create slide content")) {
    $allowed_limit = variable_get('allowed_limit', 1);
    $slides = db_query("SELECT nid, count(*) ct FROM {node} WHERE type = :type AND uid = :uid", array(':type' => 'slide' ,':uid' => $user->uid))->fetchAssoc();
    if ($slides['ct'] < $allowed_limit || in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) {
      return TRUE;
    }
    else {
      drupal_set_message('You cannot post more than one photography. But you can edit the one you posted below if yo wish to.');
      drupal_goto(drupal_get_path_alias('node/'.$slides['nid']));
    }
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

If I `dpm(slides)`, it returns the correct array and data.

But, as far as I could debug, if I try to connect a user who :

- already posted at least one node of other content type
- whether he posted or not a slide

Drupal tries to go to `node/'.$slides['nid']` and that creates an infinite loop.

**Summary :** I don't understand why my function `_mymodule_limit_slide ()` would be called out of `node/add/slide` url, or what else is wrong ?

Comment: Couple of things I would try: remove the drupal_get_path_alias and maybe put a drupal_exit(); under that line.
I can't see anything wrong with your logic though.

Comment: Thank you, Indeed I'm redirected to path alias without calling `drupal_get_path_alias`, but unfortunately this did not help.

Comment: I believe you want to hook into the node add form instead of the menu access.  I believe this is why Drupal runs your _limit_slide function every time it displays the menu.

Comment: Thank you. I need the user to be stopped and redirected before the node edit form is displayed. How would you implement your idea then ?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you add the access login in the form_alter, the user should be redirected properly. IOW something like this:

```
function yourmodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {  if($form_id == 'CONTENT-TYPE_node_form') {  global $user;
  if(user_access("create slide content")) {
    $allowed_limit = variable_get('allowed_limit', 1);
    $slides = db_query("SELECT nid, count(*) ct FROM {node} WHERE type = :type AND uid = :uid", array(':type' => 'slide' ,':uid' => $user->uid))->fetchAssoc();
    if ($slides['ct'] < $allowed_limit || in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) {
      return TRUE;
    }
    else {
      drupal_set_message('You cannot post more than one photography. But you can edit the one you posted below if yo wish to.');
      drupal_goto(drupal_get_path_alias('node/'.$slides['nid']));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Putting these checks into `form_alter` ends with same loop behaviour.

Comment: I still think form alter is a better way, because this fires only when somebody goes to the form page, as opposed to checking things on every node prepare... but there are many right solutions here :) Glad you resolved it

Comment: Well, `$slides` and subsequent `$slides['nid']` are set outside/before the if statement, and I get the right nid value. But I could not get yours working. On the other hand, it would fire each time `form_alter` is run. Which one will be used more, `form_alter` or `node_prepare` ? You pointed a good question, but I don't have the answer. :) Cheers

Comment: Yeah, which usage is higher depends on the site, iow if there are a lot of nodes or a lot of forms lol But back to your original problem, my guess is that since Drupal executed your access function every time it loaded a page and built the menu, it would then find the user couldnt access, and redirect to node/$slides['nid'] but on that node page Drupal would have to again rebuild the menus, check access, redirect and the process would repeat in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working that way :

```
function mymodule_node_prepare($node) {
  if ( empty($node->nid) && $node->type == 'slide' && !in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) {
    global $user;
    $slides = db_query("SELECT nid, count(*) ct FROM {node} WHERE type = :type AND uid = :uid", array(':type' => 'slide' ,':uid' => $user->uid))->fetchAssoc();
    $allowed_limit = variable_get('allowed_limit', 1);    

    if ($slides['ct'] >= $allowed_limit  ) {
      drupal_set_message('You cannot post more than one photography. But you can edit the one you posted below if yo wish to.');
      drupal_goto('node/'.$slides['nid']);
    }
  }
}
```

Sounds more elegant than `menu_alter()`, but I couldn't figure out what was wrong in question logic.